# PCB trace is 50 ohms, for reflection can we detect the discontinuity point?

Tags: pcb, signal, impedance, transmission-line, trace

all,

I've searched some information but still have questions.

1. If it is all impedance control from the whole trace (driver -- PCB trace - device input), does this mean no any reflection in the real world?
   if it is a very longer line, sill no reflection but concern about line degrade rise/fall times due to the series resistance?
2. I used a system ATE, automatic test equipment) to drive a voltage to a IC's input, I can also do Smith when driving.
   From the Smith chart I found there is a flat voltage at ~50% and looks like it is due to the signal reflection.
   The flat voltage stays for ~16ns and per a general calculation the trace length is ~44 inches.  ---> 16 ns / 180 ps/inch (FR-4) x 1/2 (round trip)

The IC datasheet indicates the Generator is required for 50 ohms so I think the IC's input is 50 ohms impedance as well.
[image]

My question is, ATE driver, PCB traces and device's input are all 50 ohms impedance control but the reflection still occurs.

I was thinking the reflection is due to the device's input, I tried to short a 50 ohm resistor to device's input as a far-end parallel termination but no help.
Does this mean somewhere inside the ATE the impedance is not perfect 50 ohms?
I won't be able to find out the problem location as it is inside the system without some other equipment to support?

Much appreciate all your inputs.

**Comment#1: added the shmoo chart**

It is the shmoo result from ATE for ATE driver.
[image]

Comment: What do you shmoo?

Comment: It might help if you could show the voltage close to the driver. It is certainly possible that something is not quite at 50 Ohms.

Comment: I mean, show us a scope trace. TDR should be able to elucidate exactly what is happening "down the wire."

Comment: @AliChen, I shmoo the ATE driver, which is the volt generator.

Comment: @mkeith, I can only scope the end of the trace, not able to scope close to the driver as it is inside the system. I don't have TDR equipment and is there any other ways I may try? (I have only signal generator)

Comment: I'm not sure what shmooing the driver means (ATE people have their own special terminology), but if the chart can be construed as TDR reflected wave (or as a scope waveform at driver side), the interpretation is simple: the driver drives a transmission line that is unterminated (open) at the destination end, and the length of line is about  44-53 inches.

Comment: Can you redraw the diagram or add some notation showing where the 44" trace is and where you are probing (where the voltage plot is taken from)? It is not totally clear to me. The voltage plot looks like what you get when a 50 Ohm source drives a 50 Ohm line terminated in an open circuit.